# Ruby on Rails File Read operation is not displaying properly

Tags: ruby-on-rails, file-io

I have a text file(output of my other function), need to display through ajax call. well, it is displaying the content but not the way it is. my text file is well formatted.  here is a glimpse of my code, any help will be appreciated

**Controller:**

```
require "rinruby"
class MedicationsController < ApplicationController
def  ndc_crawl
ndc = NDCCode.find_by(ndc_code: params[:ndc])
ndc.crawl
file_content=File.read("#{Rails.root}/product_info.txt") 
puts     file_content   
render text: {result: file_content}
end
end
```

**Model:**

```
require "rinruby"
class NDCCode < ActiveRecord::Base
self.table_name='ndc_codes'
def crawl
R.eval "library(rvest)"
R.eval "library(stringr)"
R.eval "load('app/models/rdata/ndc_crawler.RData')"
R.eval "ndc_crawler('#{ndc_code}')"
end
end
```

**View:**

```
$('#medications_live tbody').on('click', 'a.ndc-link', function(e) {
e.preventDefault();
$.ajax({
url: '/medications/ndc_crawl',
data: { ndc: $(this).data('product-service-id') },
dataType: 'html',
success: function(response) {
$('#myModal1').modal('show').find('.modal-body').html(response);
```

==================================================================

Output i am getting on display
https://github.com/ravi236/gitravi/blob/master/output
Output i wanted is
https://github.com/ravi236/gitravi/blob/master/Output_supposed_to_be.txt

This is the code, so i can i get formatted data as it is in .txt file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to convert plain text to html to get the desired output. Just replace the special characters with line-break tags.

```
render plain: {result: file_content.gsub(/\n|\r/, '<br>')}
```

Note: `render :text` is deprecated since 5.1.0. Use `render :plain` instead.

Comment: Hey thank you so much, i have searched like anything and tried almost all. but this worked.  except it still have {:result=>"\"  this thing at the top in display

Comment: You're welcome!
Maybe you don't need that "key" at all? Just
`render plain: file_content.gsub(/\n|\r/, '<br>')`